# Hide an element for three minutes of connectivity

Tags: javascript, events, html, user-interface, time

I have a chat application and I would like to display a "request supervisor" button to display after three minutes of the user being *connected*.  This would include a user refreshing the page.

Here is what I have, but it's really not sufficient at all;

```
//shows the tooltip in 3 minutes
window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("#panic-tooltip").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    }, 180000);
```

Obviously if the user refreshes the page it locks up.  I was thinking about using  a cookie somehow... I'd prefer not to have to have to do anything on the backend, but I might have to.  Also, I am aware that push technology would be a good solution, but that's not an option here.

I'm using `HTML5/CSS3/jQuery/jQuery UI` btw if any of that is helps.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any back-end technology that keeps track of sessions?  You could create a cookie at the beginning with the date/time when user connected, then every couple of seconds see if it has been 3 minutes since that cookie was created. If it has, display the button.

Comment: Push technology? That's slight overkill. Timing three minutes is just like you're doing, `setTimeout`. If you want to be rigorous then log the time they connected in a cookie (or local storage) and on page load check the value and calculate accordingly.

Comment: @davin - exactly I wanted to weed out any of those answers... thx for the cookie tip both of you

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up using... too bad davin or mellamokb didn't answer lol

```
if($.cookie("showPanic") == 'yes'){
    $("#panic-tooltip").fadeTo(1000, 1);
} else {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $("#panic-tooltip").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        $.cookie("showPanic", "yes");
    }, 180000);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the user changes pages every 2 minutes 59 seconds, but I assume that's the behavior you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a function to set a cookie and one to retrieve a cookie, it is relatively simple.

On first visit you set the cookie with the current time like this:

```
if(!getCooke('first_visit')) setCookie('first_visit', new Date().toString());
```

But only if the cookie is not already present.

Additionally you have an interval loop the checks for the difference in time:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    var oldDate = new Date(getCookie('first_visit')),
        newDate = new Date();

    if(newDate - oldDate > 180000){  //time is in miliseconds
        clearInterval(timer);
        //show your message here
        $("#panic-tooltip").fadeTo(1000, 1);

    } 
},1000);
```